# Multiple string check in oracle db

Tags: oracle

Say I want to check if a title name contains "stack" or contains "over" or contains "flow". Can I shorten the below code?

```
select name 
from Title
where name like '%stack%' or name like '%over%' or name like '%flow%'
;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can't find an obvious way to shorten the query using `LIKE`. You _could_ use [`REGEXP_LIKE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm), however that may have performance implications so may not necessarily be a good idea just to type less SQL. Let me know if you want me to add an example as an answer.

Comment: Yeah I can try that, if it's not a huge hindrance on speed then it should be okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* use [`REGEXP_LIKE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm), however that may have performance implications, so you may want to test it for your specific use case;

```
SELECT name 
FROM Title
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(name, '.*(stack|over|flow).*')
```

...or if you want the match case insensitive you can pass `i` as a third parameter;

```
SELECT name 
FROM Title
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(name, '.*(stack|over|flow).*', 'i');
```

[A regex101 explaining the regex itself](https://regex101.com/r/oR7lT1/1).